# How to get the json files from a value

Tags: python, json

this is my json files

```
{
  "people1": [
    {
      "name":"William",
      "age": "20",
      "location": "Bali"
    },
    {
      "name":"Jose",
      "age": "30",
      "location": "Canada"
    }
  ]
}
```

Lets say i want to get the age and location of ''William'' only. How would I do it? for now this is my code but I can't seem to get it.

code.py

```
import json

with open("names.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

for item in data["people1"]:
    print(item["name"])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it's not working

Comment: Why do you have a loop if you only want the data for one person? Your loop loops over the entire `people1` array. Simply printing `data["people1"][0]` returns the data for William: `{'name': 'William', 'age': '20', 'location': 'Bali'}` [Demo](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/WorriedValuableSpreadsheets#main.py). Are you trying to search through the array to find *any* specific person?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through your data looking for William and then do what you like with his data.

```
for item in data["people1"]:
    if item["name"] == "William":
        print(item["age"])
        print(item["location"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
import json
j_ = '''{
  "people1": [
    {
      "name":"William",
      "age": "20",
      "location": "Bali"
    },
    {
      "name":"Jose",
      "age": "30",
      "location": "Canada"
    }
  ]
}'''
j = json.loads(j_)
for x in j['people1']:
    if x['name'] == 'William':
        print(x['age'])
        print(x['location'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You do a simple for loop

```py
for i in data['people1']:
   if i['name'] == 'William':
      print(i['age'])
```